# How to create a popup menu in visual basic.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, popupmenu

How can I create a popup menu in vb 2008 for use as a context sensitive menu for when I right-click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create the context menu using the ContextMenuStrip control. Then assign that ContextMenuStrip to the ContextMenuStrip property of the form or control you want to use the context menu with.

Answer (score 5):

There's a context menu located in the Components section of the Toolbox.  You can then link this context menu to the appropriate control(s) in the Properties section of the control in the Design View.